# How to make SFSafariViewController open link in new Window (IOS Development)

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

After implemented **SFSafariViewController**. when navigatin through a web site that contains a link with **target=_blank**
or a javascript with **window.open**
the Link is opened in the same view, I would like to open it in another View, or make it create windows automatically!

Answer (score 1):

Safari View Controller does not support windows. You would be better off making your own mini web browser using WKWebView for total control and customisation as Apple also specifies in the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller